# If I have a set of coordinates, how can I get the country, only with the Requests library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, geolocation, python-requests

I need to get the country from which a set of coordinates are from:
example:

```
coords=[41.902782, 12.496366.]


output:

Italy
```

I know that this can be made by using other libraries, but I need to know if there's a way to do it only with the **requests library**.(**json** is available too)
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use some sort of API or service to achieve this. Requests just helps you, you know, make requests. I would suggest looking at the [Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) for geocoding. They are simple to setup and have good starting guides

Comment: Also, what is the reason you are limited to these two libraries?

Comment: The only problem is that you have to pay to get acces to google apis. It's for a challenge at the uni, although I don't know if it really is possible to do it without any other libraries, if it's not possible, then I guess we can use other libraries haha

Comment: I haven't used them in a while but they used to be free under a certain threshold. Try  [this](https://locationiq.com/pricing), it has a free tier.

Comment: I still have one problem I can't get just the country, since when I use the "diplay_id" key from the dictionary, it prints the whole address as a string. And when I try to to use the "address" key, to then use the "country" key I get the keyerror for "adress"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Razdi has said, you will need an API that takes your coordinates and returns a location.

This is called [reverse geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_geocoding).

Think of the Requests library like a browser URL path. All it can do is get an address of a website. However, if the address is right, and expects certain parameters, then you can access values:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'
>>> params = {'sensor': 'false', 'address': 'Mountain View, CA'}
>>> r = requests.get(url, params=params)
>>> results = r.json()['results']
>>> location = results[0]['geometry']['location']
>>> location['lat'], location['lng']
```

What you want is something like this:

```
import geocoder
g = geocoder.google([45.15, -75.14], method='reverse')
```

But you're not allowed to use the package... so you'll need to be more verbose:

import requests

```
def example():
    # grab some lat/long coords from wherever. For this example,
    # I just opened a javascript console in the browser and ran:
    #
    # navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p) {
    #   console.log(p);
    # })
    #
    latitude = 35.1330343
    longitude = -90.0625056

    # Did the geocoding request comes from a device with a
    # location sensor? Must be either true or false.
    sensor = 'true'

    # Hit Google's reverse geocoder directly
    # NOTE: I *think* their terms state that you're supposed to
    # use google maps if you use their api for anything.
    base = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"
    params = "latlng={lat},{lon}&sensor={sen}".format(
        lat=latitude,
        lon=longitude,
        sen=sensor
    )
    url = "{base}{params}".format(base=base, params=params)
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json()['results'][0]['formatted_address']
```

[Code snippet taken and modified from here.](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/5397472)